# Lambda with if elif else

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda

I try to put more than 2 conditions in my lambda.

`df['AA'] = df['AA'].apply(lambda x : "Suppression" if x==1 or x==61 else "Check")`
I want to add more conditions like `elif x==90 "Dont Suppress" elif x==93 "..."` then my `else "check"`.
Is it possible with a lambda? I must have a syntax issue.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't use lambda, use normal function instead.

Comment: or use a list `"Suppression" if x in [1,61,90]`

Comment: Could I have some help on the function? Don't how to put all that in it. Not comfortable with functions

Comment: Some combo of `d = {1:"Suppression", 61:"Suppression", 90:"Dont Suppress"}` and `d.get(x, "Check")` to get the associated value or the default of "Check" if `x` is not present in the dict.